# Binary search tree search rerror in c

Tags: c, binary-tree

```
    void binarySearch(int);
    void createB(void);
    int A[]={45,16,22,51,18,72,33,64,40};
    int i,j,x,y;

    int main(){

            scanf("%d",&y);
createB();
            binarySearch(y);
    return 0;
    }

createB(){


   B[0]=A[0];
    for(i=1; i<10; i++)
    {
        x=A[i];
        j=0;
        while(B[j]!=0)
        {
            if (x<B[j])
            {
                j=2*j+1;
            }
            else
            {
                j=2*j+2;
            }
        }
        B[j]=x;
    }
}}

    void binarySearch(int y){
    i=0;
    while((B[i]!=0)&&(y!=B[i])){
        if(y<B[i]){
            i=2i+1;
        }
        else{
            i=2i+2;
        }

    }
```

My code is that. It creates binary search tree correctly.

```
45 16 51 0 22 0 72 etc
```

Then for example if i search 45 or 16 it finds correctly. But for 66, or something, it goes infinite loop ( i tested with a lot of printf's). After first if, i becomes 2 (i*2+2) for 66 but then i stays 2 and infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
i=2i+1; // missing the '*' multiply
```

Comment: Oh thanks :D what an small mistake but i couldnot see fou hours

Comment: that shouldn't even compile.